# Django How to Upload an Image to Form

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

This is my code associated with the form:

```
# models

class Date(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    place = models.ForeignKey('Place', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)


class Photo(models.Model):
    date = models.ForeignKey('Date', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name='Photos', upload_to='media/date/photos/')

# form

class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        model = Date
        exclude = ('user',)

# view

class CreateDateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'app/date/form.html'
    form_class = DateForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        form.save() # by the way why do I save this form? Is it okay to save it in form_valid method?
        photos = self.request.FILES.getlist('image')
        for photo in photos:
            Photo.objects.create(image=photo)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

The issue is how to save Photo objects if it requires a **Date** model id. It raises **NOT NULL constraint failed: app_photo.date_id**
As I understand I have to write something like:

```
Photo.objects.create(date=date_from_the_form, image=photo)
```

But how to get the pk from the Date model? Hope you understand my problem, if any questions don't hesitate to write down below in comments section. Thanks in advance!

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QJCZ.png)

Comment: Show me the error and the DateForm

Comment: Okay, I'll edit in a few seconds

Comment: And the DateForm?

Comment: Sorry, thought already added. Check now

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the date object first. Also, is each date going to be unique? If so, you need to change your model Meta declarations to include `unique_together`.

You also need to avoid the for loop when creating each object. It's very expensive because it's going to make a round trip to the database for each save() called. That's what `bulk_create` is for, which limits your database touches to one command to make many objects.

Here's pseudocode to get you going:

```
if len(photos) > 0:  # don't create a date if there aren't photos
  date = Date() # add your arguments

  filtered = Date.objects.filter(date=date)

  date = date.create() if not filtered.exists() else date = filtered[0]  # but this is potentially dangerous if you risk duplicate dates. Only use this if you know it's the correct date
  photos = [Photo(date=date,image=p) for p in photos]
  Photo.objects.bulk_create(photos)
```

Good luck!

Comment: There should be easier way to do it though. Thanks anyways

Comment: It already inherits a CreateView, so it will populate the date twice in your case

Answer (score 0):

You need save the photo object:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    form.save() # by the way why do I save this form? Is it okay to save it in form_valid method?
    photos = self.request.FILES.getlist('image')
    for photo in photos:
        temp = Photo.objects.create(image=photo)
        temp.save()
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: No dude, creating the object already saves it.